# Docker build from Dockerfile shows "ADD failed - No such file or directory"

Tags: docker, nginx

When I try to build the following (simple) NGINX docker container https://github.com/MarvAmBass/docker-nginx-ssl-secure, it always fails with the following error: `stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder00Whatever/basic.conf: no such file or directory`

My directory looks like this:

```
├── basic.conf
├── Dockerfile
├── entrypoint.sh
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── ssl.conf
```

Running the command `sudo docker build - < Dockerfile` as root user doesn't change a thing.
Does anyone have a solution here?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it... Running `docker build . -f Dockerfile` instead of `docker build - < Dockerfile` did the trick. I will put this as an answer, too...

Comment: Why -1??????????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, for me it worked to use `docker build . -f Dockerfile` instead of `docker build - < Dockerfile` (which was the suggestion from the offical docker documentation by the way: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tarball-contexts). The solution was taken from github: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34986#issuecomment-343680872

Answer (score 4):

The most common causes of this issue are:

1. Incorrect path
2. Having docker-builder in your `.dockerignore`

Answer (score 3):

I found the same error message when I used **docker-compose.yml** with follows directory structure. I fixed it by updating the dockerfile path in the **docker-compose.yml** as follows.

```
.docker      
├── basic.conf
├── Dockerfile
```

My **docker-compose.yml** look like this when I found the error

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: .docker/nginx
```

I have solved the problem by update the  **docker-compose.yml** as follows.

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: .docker/nginx/Dockerfile
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not know what this has to do with the question?

Comment: I found the same error message when I used **docker-compose.yml** with the directory structure above. I fixed it by updating the dockerfile path in the **docker-compose.yml** and it can be fixed that error message.

Answer (score 1):

Hells bells all - for further clarification, because I needed it and it took me a bit to figure this out on my own:

With an ADD in the Dockerfile, you need to be in the directory relative to wherever you're adding - not relative to the Dockerfile.

```
ADD directory1\directory2\filename.jar app.jar
```

And your file structure is:

```
home
|-directory1
  |-directory2
```

You need to be in home when you use:

```
docker build . -f filepathToDocker/Dockerfile
```

I imagine this might be true for COPY as well, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when I run docker in Ubuntu machine. I could resolve it by mentioning ${pwd} before the source file in ADD instruction.

Here, I had to copy 'apps' from /home/arun/ks/ to / in container.

So, I made a change in Dockerfile as below.

ADD ${PWD}/apps /apps

Then I built the docker image from the location of source file instead of location of Dockerfile.

$ pwd

/home/arun/ks/

$ ls
apps web

$ sudo docker image build -t image-name . -f path-to-the-dockerfile

Here, we should use both . and -f option.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibility is incorrect path in source

```
ADD ./directory/basic.conf /dir/
```

instead of

```
ADD basic.conf /dir/
```